# Show that $H:=\{m/2^n:m \in \mathbb{Z}, n\in \mathbb{N}\}/\mathbb{Z}$ doesn't have a proper maximal subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show that every proper subgroup of $H:=\{m/2^n:m \in \mathbb{Z}, n\in \mathbb{N}\}/\mathbb{Z}$ is contained in a larger proper subgroup of H.

I've no idea. I wanted to prove by contradiction, for example, assume $H_1$ is the proper maximal subgroup of H, and I wanted to characterize what the maximal group would look like and then derive a contradiction. But I just messed up. It would be tedious if I posted what I had done here.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Pick $m/2^n\not\in H_1$ so that $m/2^{n-1}\in H_1$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!